# Get visible lines in Scintilla.NET component

Tags: c#, api, scintilla

How can I get the first visible (top) and last visible (bottom) lines number for Scintilla component in C#? For example, if I scroll the text and I am able to see lines 5-41 (no folding, it is the number of lines which are shown by the component at the moment; the rest, you have to scroll to them), how do I get those numbers programatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you ever want to find out how to do something with Scintilla, your first stop should always be the core [Scintilla Documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html). It is comprehensive, and usually kept fully up to date.

The correct way to do what you want is to use the [SCI_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE) message to get the first line, and then use the [SCI_LINESONSCREEN](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_LINESONSCREEN) message to calculate the last line.

There are probably Scintilla.NET wrapper methods for those messages. But the [Scintilla.NET documentation](https://scintillanet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ScintillaNET%20Types&referringTitle=Documentation) seems very poor, and doesn't provide a complete description of its API - although I suppose you could always use the `SendMessageDirect` method (which *is* documented) to send the messages directly if you can't guess what the wrapper method is called.

Comment: Thanks, I have finally made it work with your suggested answer. Thank you very much man!

Answer (score 2):

For ScintillaNET 2 it would be:

```
scintilla.Lines.FirstVisibleIndex
scintilla.Lines.VisibleCount
```

In ScintillaNET 3 names were refactored to be more like core scintilla:

```
scintilla.FirstVisibleLine
scintilla.LinesOnScreen
```